# How to Getting the Variable from Function in as3 without using get ,set method?

Tags: actionscript-3

Hai am Getting trouble to retrive the values from function(addText).i Called from another function onFullScreen().I dont know how Can i do this,Kindly Help me?Here i attach my Code

```
private function addText()
    {


        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ncOnStatus);



        function ncOnStatus(infoObject:NetStatusEvent)
        {
            trace("nc: "+infoObject.info.code+" ("+infoObject.info.description+")");

            if (infoObject.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
            {
                initSharedObject(chatSharedObjectName);
            }


        }
        function formatMessage(chatData:Object)
        {

            trace("room"+chatData.message);
            number = chatData.txtalign;//i want to retrive the value of number
            number.toString();
            return number;


        }
        function syncEventHandler(ev:SyncEvent)
        {
            var infoObj:Object = ev.changeList;

            // if first time only show last 4 messages in the list
            if (lastChatId == 0)
            {
                lastChatId = Number(textchat_so.data["lastChatId"]) - 1;
                if (lastChatId < 0)
                    lastChatId = 0;
            }

        }

        function connectSharedObject(soName:String)
        {


            textchat_so = SharedObject.getRemote(soName, nc.uri)

            // add new message to the chat box as they come in
            textchat_so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC, syncEventHandler)

            textchat_so.connect(nc) 


        }


        function connectSharedObjectRes(soName:String)
        {

            connectSharedObject(soName)
            trace(soName)
        }

        function initSharedObject(soName:String)
        {
            // initialize the shared object server side
            nc.call("initSharedObject", new Responder(connectSharedObjectRes), soName)


        }
                    }
```

i using the variable in another function ,but I cannot retrive the Value.

```
    private function onFullScreen(event:FullScreenEvent):void
    {
                       mediaContainer.addMediaElement(alert);
            alert.alert("Error",number);// if i cannot retrive the value  hnumber here
             }
```

Comment: This code is not valid Java.  Why is the question tagged as Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addText() method is asynchronous, meaning that you can't simply call it , you need to wait for the event listener to return a value.

I'm not sure why you would feel the need to enclose all these functions, it's not very legible and I doubt it's necessary. You're also missing quite a few semi colons...

In any case , I couldn't see where the formatMessage() method was called, it seems that's the only place where the "number" variable gets defined.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable outside the scope of the functions.

```
private var num:int;
```

Then in your addText function, assign a value to the variable:

```
num = infoObject.info.code;
```

Then in your onFullScreen function, access the num variable:

```
 alert.alert("Error", num);
```